# flash.net.Socket and C++ winsock WSAECONNRESET

Tags: c++, flash, actionscript-3, sockets, winsock

I'm working on a flash application that needs to communicate with my C++ server for things like account validation and state updates. I have a non-blocking TCP socket on the server listening on a specific port.

The process goes like this:

1. Socket listens on server machine
2. Flash connects using a flash.net.Socket
3. Server accepts socket connection
4. Flash sends a policy file request
5. Server sends policy file data
6. Flash accepts connection

Two problems occur from here on out. When I send bytes from flash the server doesn't recognize it at all but it doesn't block either. I just recv 0 bytes. When I send bytes from the server after sending the policy file I gives me a WSAECONNRESET error.

Resources for Flash communicating with C or C++ is very limited so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the flash client sends `"<policy-file-request/>"` the server should send the file and then close the connection.
The client will need to reconnect after it receives the policy.
Trust me on this.